# its javascript code can you please tell me why it is not working

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

function changeValue()
{
    var list, index, element;
    list = document.getElementsByClassName('box-title');
    for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index){
        element = list[index].innerHTML;
        if(element == "Related Products"){
            list[index].innerHTML = "Choose Extra To make It More Special";
            alert("Page is loaded");
        }
    }
} 
</script>
</head>
<body onload =”changeValue()”>
<div class="box-title">Related Products</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh man make your code readable!

Comment: What doesn't work?  What's is the code supposed to do?  What text editor are you using?  You have some bizarre characters that are usually only a result of using a Microsoft product to edit code.  You should use a standard text editor.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wmaca/ - i plugged in your code and it seems to work fine after changing the quotes

Comment: Don't use Microsoft products to edit code!! (unless you're using Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1):

Mayby you have to remove the space between onload and = and change the weird double quote (also known as 'smart quotes')

So this:

```
<body onload =”changeValue()”>
```

will be this:

```
<body onload="changeValue()">
```

Comment: space is legal. smart quotes are not. was not my downvote.

Comment: I agree, the space isn't the issue, but the quotes are definitely causing the error.

Comment: wasn't sure about the space, but by doubt, you can always try ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the `++` operator?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

function changeValue()
{
 var list, index, element;
 list = document.getElementsByClassName('box-title');
 for (index = 0; index < list.length; index++)
 {
  element = list[index].innerHTML;
    if(element == "Related Products")
{
  list[index].innerHTML = "Choose Extra To make It More Special";
  alert("Page is loaded");
}
}

} 
</script>
</head>
<body onload =”changeValue()”>
<div class="box-title">Related Products</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of reasons for which it may not be working.

For example, [`getElementsByClassName()`](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname) might be unsupported by the browser.

Comment: now its giving Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined error.